# UI elements disappearing on certain dpi scales

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10

I've got this windows 10 store app (using the Windows 8.1 Store app libs/platform) which has been cooperating nicely on different screen sizes and DPI settings up until now. My latest feature is being shown correct on my 27" Dell monitor (2560x1440, 100% scale), but when shown on a tablet (2560x1440, 200% scale) the ui elements are visualized incorrectly. The issue is also present in the visual studio simulator when using the same screen settings.

My user control which is being displayed inconsistently consists of 4 Line objects composing a rectangle (the white one in the pictures).

Visualized correctly on 2560x1440 @ 100% for the blue camera (it is also working for the red and green):
[image: Visualized correctly on 2560x1440 @ 100%]

Each of the three icons (red, green and blue cameras) has one of these user controls attached to it (it is only active for one at the time - hence only visualized for the blue camera in the above picture).

Visualized incorrectly on 2560x1440 @ 200% for the blue camera:
[image]

Visualized correctly on 2560x1440 @ 200% for the green camera:
[image]

However for the red camera, it is not showing at all when scale is 200%. I find it kind of puzzling that the same user control can display in three different ways (one correctly, the second only with the bottom line and the third not at all). They are consistently being displayed like this (no randomness).

When I change the scaling to 175% they are all showing correcly. I've tried changing the stroke thickness of the lines, but that didn't help. I guess there is some mechanism in the dpi scaling of this kind of apps I've overlooked. Any help is very much appreciated!

Kind regards.